# How to delete a file in a directory in C++?

Tags: c++, file, eclipse-cdt, delete-file

I have a piece of code in an Eclipse IDE on Windows 10 where I'd like to delete a .txt file from a directory different from the one I'm working in. I've tried with `std::remove("/SomeFolder/AnotherFolder/FileToBeRemoved.txt")` but it didn't do anything (I've included the `<stdlib.h>` library). The file is closed.

I also tried `std::filesystem::remove("/SomeFolder/AnotherFolder/FileToBeRemoved.txt")` adding the `<filesystem>` library as showed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove), but it gave me the error: `no member named 'filesystem' in namespace 'std'`.

What's the proper way to delete a file specifying the file directory?

Below there's the code with std::remove. The goal is to delete the first row from file_to_read, and I've found online that it can be done using a temp file, then removing the original file, and then renaming the temp file as the original file.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <string>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <sstream>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <filesystem>

  [...]

  std::ofstream temp("/ProgramIUse/Samples/MyFolder/Subfolder/temp.txt", std::ios_base::app);
  std::ifstream file_to_read("/ProgramIUse/Samples/MyFolder/Subfolder/originalFile.txt", std::ios_base::app);
  count = 0;
  while(getline(file_to_read,tempRow)){
      count = count +1;
      if(count>1){
          temp << tempRow << endl;
      }
  }
  temp.close();
  file_to_read.close();
  std::remove("/ProgramIUse/Samples/MyFolder/Subfolder/originalFile.txt");
  std::rename("/ProgramIUse/Samples/MyFolder/Subfolder/temp.txt","/ProgramIUse/Samples/MyFolder/Subfolder/originalFile.txt");
```

The code with std::filesystem::remove is the same, but obviously with std::filesystem::remove

UPDATE: I've switched to the fopen function with "w" mode and added C: at the beginning of the path (I didn't put it before because the ofstream/ifstream functions worked without it).
Now it works and does the same job that I wanted to do with the remove function.

Comment: It's `C++17`. Did you enable it?

Comment: I don't think so. How can I do it?

Comment: @SuperFluo *I have a piece of code in an Eclipse IDE on Windows 10* -- Neither Eclipse or Windows 10 are C++ compilers.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: How should I know? You didn't mention your compiler.

Comment: *What's the proper way to delete a file specifying the file directory?* -- Did you check why the file couldn't be deleted?  It may have nothing to do with the coding involved to delete files.  What you're showing *is* one way to delete a file.

Comment: The compiler is MinGW64

Comment: [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) does not delete files. maybe you meant [`unlink`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html)?

Comment: @rustyx -- There is an [overload that does this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've checked. In the code I open the file with std::ofstream, I write some lines in it, I close it with FileName.close(), and then I'd like to delete it. If I check the file, it has the lines I wrote in it, so everything went right until the last step. So I don't know what could be wrong other than coding.

Comment: @SuperFluo *I've checked.* -- But we can't check.  Let's see the code.

Comment: @SuperFluo Is this your actual code?  Where is the closing `}` for the `while()` loop and `if()` statements?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- I didn't see them when I put the code here. The code has the closing `}`.

Comment: @SuperFluo -- Please check the return code for `std::remove`.  The second thing you should do is write a very simple one line `main` program that tries to delete that file.  Forget about while loops and if statements -- can you write a one line `main` that simply deletes that file using `std::remove`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- The return code is -1

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- Unfortunately is not so simple because I'm using a simulator based on Eclipse, and I can't run .cc files. I only can run simulation files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232144/discussion-between-superfluo-and-paulmckenzie).

Comment: Return code -1 means it failed. In that case you can check the error reason in `errno` and in windows, `GetLastError()`.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
no member named 'filesystem' in namespace 'std'.
```

indicates that you have not included the correct header file, or that the version of c++ you've specified does not include these symbols.

As per https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove, these require including

```
#include <filesystem>
```

Further, this function takes a filesystem:path, not a std::string or a `char const *`, so passing "" constants won't work.

Comment: Yes, I've added that #include

Comment: ...Or the compiler is set to a standard prior c++17 (since the OP uses a flavor of gcc, in the build options/compiler arguments should ensure `-std=c++17` or higher)